# Ruby on Rails Formtastic Multiple Options in Member_Label

Tags: forms, list, variables, ruby-on-rails-3.1, formtastic

I have a relational model where users have managers that are also users. The below code works great and does exactly what it's suppose to,  but it's only displaying the first name of the manager. I'm trying to get this to show both the first name and the last name of the manager.

```
<%= sf.input :managers, :as => :check_boxes, :member_label => (:firstname)  ,:input_html => { :size => 20, :multiple => true}%>
```

The other field i'm trying to add is the `:lastname`. I cannot figure out how to get `:member_label` to take both fields.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. By using the Proc.new, I was able to add in both first name and last name.

```
<%= sf.input :managers, :as => :check_boxes, :member_label => Proc.new { |t| h(t.firstname + " " + t.lastname) }  ,:input_html => { :size => 20, :multiple => true}%>
```

Comment: Gross, but effective.  Nice.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier Agreed. Luckily that project has been sunsetted.